# combining arrays into matrix - adding delimiters between cells

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to merge two files and plus the second column from two files.

file1.

```
001    A
002    B
003    C
004    D
```

file2.

```
002    D
003    D
005    E
006    F
```

should be merged into file 3 as below.

```
001    A
002    B D
003    C D
004    D
005    E
006    F
```

I tried this command, suggested by andreatsh here: [Merge two files and plus the second column using AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329485/merge-two-files-and-plus-the-second-column-using-awk?newreg=e03c06d6ecfd4addad0d988bbbf0ff0d):

```
$ awk '{ z[$1]=z[$1]$2 } END { for (i in z) print i, z[i] }' file1  file2
002 BD
003 CD
004 D
```

etc...

That's very close, but how could I add a space between the letters?

e.g. instead of "BD" in the first line, rather "B D"

Comment: You can straightforwardly modify `{print $1, a[$1]$2}` to `{print $1, a[$1] OFS $2}` or indeed `{print $1, a[$1] "any string here" $2}`

Comment: What should the output be if `004 D` also existed in file2 - `004 D` or `004 D D`? Does the order of output lines matter and, if so, what should it be based on?

Comment: Hi Ed, I have pre-processed the files so that the column order is always as expected. as a newbie, I have to break the overall pipeline into little chunks :)

Comment: @steff2j thanks, and how about how to handle duplicate column values? Btw if you don't put `@EdMorton` in the comment then I don't get notified that you've posted anything for me to read.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it with Awk, but Join was born for this task:

```
join -a1 -a2 file1 file2
```

Output from given samples:

```
001 A
002 B D
003 C D
004 D
005 E
006 F
```

Note that the files need to be sorted before running `join`. If your shell supports it, you can do it in one step using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
join -a1 -a2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: super elegant, can't believe I couldn't get that. can this work for more than two files. the lists are pre-sorted, so that is not an issue.

Comment: @steff2j According to Join's manual, only two files can be given, so not in a single command. You could create a simple shell loop to handle various files, but in that case I think I'd go for Awk, because shell loops are slow.

Answer (score 3):

The right tool for this is indeed `join`, [as Quasimodo showed you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619476/22222), but you can also use the same awk command with a very minor modification:

```
$  awk '{ z[$1]=z[$1]" "$2 } END { for (i in z) print i, z[i] }' file1  file2
002  B D
003  C D
004  D
005  E
006  F
001  A
```

I only changed `z[$1]=z[$1]$2`  to `z[$1]=z[$1]" "$2`.

Comment: amazing - thank you!  This works well for combining multiple files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I added `004 D` to file2 so we'd have a non-obvious case to test with. Given that, either this:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -s file1 file2 |
awk '
    $1 != prev { if (NR>1) print ""; printf "%s", $1; prev=$1 }
    { printf " %s", $2 }
    END { print "" }
'
001 A
002 B D
003 C D
004 D D
005 E
006 F
```

or this:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -s file1 file2 |
awk '
    $1 != prev{if (NR>1) print ""; printf "%s", $1; prev=$1; delete seen }
    !seen[$2]++ { printf " %s", $2 }
    END { print "" }
'
001 A
002 B D
003 C D
004 D
005 E
006 F
```

depending on how you want duplicate values for the same key handled. Just list as many files as you like on the `sort` line. The above assumes GNU sort for `-s` to retain input order for the same keys, if you don't have that and actually need it there are simple alternatives. You can also trivially tweak that to always get the A B C, etc. to be in alphabetic order on each output line rather than the order they occur in each input file if you like, e.g.:

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
001    A
002    E
003    F
004    D

==> file2 <==
002    D
003    D
004    D
005    E
006    F

==> file3 <==
001    A
002    E
003    C
004    D
```

```
$ sort -s file* | awk '$1 != prev{if (NR>1) print ""; prev=$1; delete seen; printf "%s", $1} !seen[$2]++{printf " %s", $2} END{print ""}'
001 A
002 D E
003 C D F
004 D
005 E
006 F
```